# Convex set without zero

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\emptyset \neq A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set with $0 \notin A$.
Then there exist a $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v \cdot a \geq 0$ for all $a \in A$ and there exists $a_0 \in A$ with $v \cdot a_0 > 0$.

How can I proof this?
For $n=1$ and $n=2$ I can somehow understand that the statement is true but I have no idea why the general case is true.

Comment: Convex sets that don't contain zero cannot wrap around it. Therefore, you should be able to find a half space containing A and from there get the vectors you want. This is not a proof but it is conceptually why it is true.

Comment: You presumably mean $0\notin A$ rather than $0\ne A$.  You also presumably mean that $a_0\in A$.

Comment: You could take a look at [Hahn Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem).

Comment: @JohnDouma: Ah, now I can see why this statement is true. Unfortunately, I still cannot proof it for the general case. For $n=2$ if (for example) the convex set is down and right of the line $f(x) = mx, m > 0$ then I can choose $v = (1,-\frac{1}{m})$ to get the result. For other convex sets I can do something similiar. But I can't generalize it...

Comment: @ForgotALot: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @NateRiver: Is it possible to prove this elementary? I doubt, I'm allowed to use the theorem you mentioned.

Comment: hint: project $0$ onto the closure of $A$.

Comment: @user251257: Oh, with that projection I obtain an vector that is orthogonal to $A$, right? With your comment I noticed that the vector in my example is orthogonal to the line. So... are you implying that this vector that I obtain from the projection is already the vector I'm looking for?

Comment: @Fabi orthogonal is little bit strong. but basically yes. you only need to check the conditions

Comment: @Fabi you still need some argument if $0$ is a closure point of $A$.

Comment: @user251257: Which conditions?
With the projection theorem I obtain a vector $v$ on the closure of $A$ such that $||0-v|| \leq ||0-a||$ for all $a$ in the closure of $A$. From there, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a more or less complete proof on Wikipedia: [Hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem).**

Here is a proof for the case $0\notin \bar A$. I do not know an "elementary" proof for the case $0\in\bar A\setminus A$.

Let $v\in \bar A$ the projection of $0$ onto $\bar A$.
that is, $\|v\| = \inf_{a\in A} \|a\|$. Since $0\notin \bar A$, it follows $v\ne 0$.
Further for every $a\in A\setminus\{ v \}$, $d = a - v$, and $t\in(0,1)$
we have $v + td \in A$ and
$$ 0\le \frac1t (\| v + td \|^2 - \|v\|^2) = 2 v\cdot d + t\|d\|^2 \to 2v\cdot d $$
for $t\to 0$.
Thus, it follows 
$$ v\cdot a = v\cdot(v+d) = \underbrace{v\cdot v}_{> 0} + \underbrace{v\cdot d}_{\ge 0} > 0.$$